# How to check if function is defined in system header files within ModulePass in LLVM Instrumentation pass?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, instrumentation

I'm implementing a custom LLVM modulePass in (Transforms/Instrumentation), which performs some action on functions. I'm using Module::iterator to iterate through the functions in a Module. How can i check if any of these function are coming from system header files. Any ideas how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Clang has SourceLocations for all declarations, but that information is not converted to LLVM IR where the ModulePass's run -- except for [debug information](https://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html) if debug info or coverage is enabled. Debug information is best effort, but if you haven't run any other transforms since clang emitted the IR, then it will usually work.

This is an intentional design decision, LLVM normally shouldn't be treating system and non-system functions differently. There's an exception localized inside [lib/Transforms/Utils/SimplifyLibCalls.cpp](https://llvm.org/doxygen/SimplifyLibCalls_8cpp_source.html) that optimizes based on the names of well-known library functions. What makes this safe is that the user of LLVM would know whether or not these functions the ones defined by the language standard, and choose whether or not to apply this optimization.

Comment: Debug Information will be good to get access to metadata attached with an instruction. However, in my scenario I don't want to generate IR for system header functions.  Also, for the second option did you mean to say to call this API inside my modulepass: ignoreCallingConv(LibFunc Func) to get rid of system function.

Comment: A ModulePass runs in LLVM after IR has been generated and can't affect whether IR is generated.

Changing what clang emits either requires hacking Clang's source code in lib/CodeGen to not emit the functions you don't want, or modifying the input source code to not allow the function bodies to be emitted.

Comment: Debug information for whole functions can be found starting with the !llvm.dbg.cu metadata (CU referring to DWARF Compilation Unit), instead of per-instruction metadata.

Comment: Not ignoreCallingConv, but TargetLibraryInfo::getLibFunc(Function*, LibFunc&) which will return true when the Function* is a known library call and set the LibFunc value to the known library function (LibFunc_strcat, etc.).

TLI doxygen: https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1TargetLibraryInfo.html